# How to parse childrenNodes using xml javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I am attempting to take this sample xml response and parse both the child and children nodes of this xml. The Prin and Role objects will be used to create related records where the PrinID of the main record will be set to the Role of the related child record.

The challenge I am having is looping through the child object and then immediately parsing the children records. The code I have written has does both individually which does not allow me to create a related record for each Role.

If I take the same logic and change the getElementsByTagName to Role, it simply parses those records without any relationship to its parent object.

How could I write the second loop or iterator so that it gets the `PrinID` of the main record while looping through the roles of its children records.

```
<Prin>
    <PrinName>John</PrinName>
    <PrinID>12345</PrinID>
    <Role>
        <Code>1111</Code>
    </Role>
    <Role>
        <Code>2222</Code>
    </Role>
</Prin>

<Prin>
    <PrinName>James</PrinName>
    <PrinID>45678</PrinID>
    <Role>
        <Code>3333</Code>
    </Role>
    <Role>
        <Code>4444</Code>
    </Role>
</Prin>

var prinID="";
var prinList=prinDoc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("Prin");

for (var i=0;i<prinList.getLength();i++){
    var childList=prinList.item(i).getChildNodes();
    for (var j=0;j<childList.getLength();j++){
        var childNode=childList.item(j);
        if (childNode.getNodeName()=="PrinName"){
            prinID=childNode=getTextContent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var prinID="";
var prinList=prinDoc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("Prin");

for (var i=0;i<prinList.getLength();i++){
    var prinObject = printList.getItem(i);

    var prinID = prinObject.getElementsByTagName("PrinID").getTextContent();
    var roleList=prinObject.getElementsByTagName("Role");
    for (var j=0;j<roleList.getLength();j++){
        var roleObject = roleList.item(j);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Using your logic, I am able to return the correct number of "Prin" objects.  However, I am getting undefined on the prinObject variable. getItem(i) returns undefined and Item(i) returns null. Any suggestions?